# android crashes while using json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

below i have posted my JSONParser code:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSONN ", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

here i use my function to start login :

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password){

    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL+login_tag+".php", params);

    return json;
}
```

i use my functions in an Async task like below:

```
public void login(View view){
    new ProcessLogin().execute();
}

/**
 * Async Task to get and send data to My Sql database through JSON respone.
 **/
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String username, password;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        username = usernameField.getText().toString();
        password = passwordField.getText().toString();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(username, password);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

        try {

            int code = json.getInt("code");

            Log.d("myLog", "JSON get code :" + String.valueOf(code));

            if (code == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                       finish();
                } else {


                }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
//echo "Welcome, I am connecting Android to PHP, MySQL";

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//$username = 'admin';
//$password = 'admin';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];





//Für die Überprüfung
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user where Username='$username' and Password='$password'");


 //if($result){




//$user = $user_details 
//$flag['code'] =0;
$response['code'] = 0;

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
    $flag['code']=1;

    //Für UserDetails

    $user_details = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    //User wird im JSON Object gespeichert
    $response["code"] = 1;
    $response["user"]["user_id"] = $user_details["user_id"];
    $response["user"]["username"] = $user_details["Username"];
    $response["user"]["password"] = $user_details["Password"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user_details["E-Mail"];



} else {
    $response['code'] = 0;
    //$flag['code']=0;

}

// }    


//print(json_encode($flag));
//print(json_encode($user_details));
print json_encode($response);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i know that it would be better to hash my passwords, but i want to do this later on.
i added more logs and now i have this log :

08-18 14:03:14.313    1444-1459/? E/HTTPClient﹕ org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@1abaea2f
08-18 14:03:14.317    1444-1459/? E/Buffered Reader﹕ java.io.BufferedReader@244a383c
08-18 14:03:14.322    1444-1459/? E/String Builder﹕ {"code":1,"user":{"user_id":"3","username":"david","password":"david","email":"david"}}
08-18 14:03:14.322    1444-1459/? E/JSON﹕ {"code":1,"user":{"user_id":"3","username":"david","password":"david","email":"david"}}
08-18 14:03:14.439        55-55/? D/gralloc﹕ Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
08-18 14:03:14.439        55-55/? E/libEGL﹕ called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
08-18 14:03:14.440        55-55/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 0
08-18 14:03:14.440        55-55/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot

the app doesnt make screenshots or something like this. 
i think the error could be with the JSON Object

this is just a part of it , but i think this should be enough.

thanks for any helps or advises

Comment: Hard to figure out from the log that you provided what might be causing the crash...

Comment: @user2260040 i added more logs now maybe you can help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see where you start the activity, you just finish the current one try this:

```
Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(upanel);
//finish();
```

Other than that, JSON looks valid and logs do not show crash.

Comment: i have to say thank you , this worked for me. i was very stupid and make comment lines bevor the start activity() thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your code keeps crashing, because you initialize the variables in a way it's not meant to be. Please put them outside the try-catch block, like:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

try {
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
} catch(...) {
    ...
}
```

Be aware to close your streams properly. A correct stream opening-closing behaviour should be coded like:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    try {
       reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    } finally {
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If this is not helping, please provide us more specific info, where exactly the code keeps crashing and attach error messages to your post. Otherwise we are not able to help you properly.

Comment: ok i changend my code like you said and added more LOGS , now i get more logs like this , can you tell me something about thjs ? i put tmy new log in my post